# Tank movement based on track speeds

Tags: rotation, movement

I want a system, where a tank moves and rotates based on the speeds I give him for the two tracks, for example, if I give the left track a speed of 1 and the right one a speed of -1, then I want the tank to stay still and rotate right, while if I give the left track 1 and the right track -0.5, I want it to rotate, but at the same time move forward[image]

Of course the speeds will be between -1 and 1

Comment: Average the speeds to get forward speed, take difference and divide by tank radius to get the angular velocity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disclaimer: this is based on intuition only, and there's definitely a missing piece for it to be mathematically exact. However, as far as I can tell, it should be a good enough approximation for small displacement values.

The idea is that the center of each tread describes a perfect motion, without skidding. Let's draw a diagram:

[image]

**O** is your tank's origin, **L** and **R** are the treads' centers. Then you'd perform as follows:

- **L** and **R** are found by taking the left and right orthogonal rotations of your direction vector **d**, and adding them to the origin;
- **L'** and **R'** are found by applying the two lateral speeds to **L** and **R** WRT the direction vector.
  i.e. **L' = L + speed(L) x d** and **R' = R + speed(R) x d**;
- **O'** is the middle of **[L'R']**, i.e. **(L' + R') / 2**;
- The new direction vector is orthogonal to **[L'R']**.

The approximation comes from the fact that **L'R' > LR**, that is, the tank actually stretches slightly when turning. Fixing that would require more advanced tools (some sort of curved vector ? I have no clue :p). However, as long as the speeds for each frame remain relatively small, this should be good enough.

Answer (score 0):

The following example code shows a simple way to move a tank around realistically. It animates a 2D tank from a bird's eye view, but the calculations are the same in any case.

It assumes you have created a sprite named `tank`, and that you have
centred its origin. There are some general notes after the code.

```
const hone = function(current, target) {

    // This helper takes current and target speeds, and returns
    // the value that the current speed should update to next.

    return current - Math.sign(current - target) / 100;
};

let speed, differential; // the tank speed and track differential

// The user can only set the *target* speed of a track. The actual
// track will usually take some time to reach that speed:

let leftSpeed = 0;  // the actual speed of the left track
let rightSpeed = 0; // the actual speed of the right track
let leftTargetSpeed = 0;  // the target speed of the left track
let rightTargetSpeed = 0; // the target speed of the right track

engine.update = function() {

    // Update the target speeds, then update the actual speeds:

    [leftTargetSpeed, rightTargetSpeed] = ui.levers.getState();
    leftSpeed = hone(leftSpeed, leftTargetSpeed);
    rightSpeed = hone(rightSpeed, rightTargetSpeed);

    // Calculate the `speed` and `differential`:

    speed = (leftSpeed + rightSpeed) / 2;
    differential = leftSpeed - rightSpeed;

    // Then the magic happens...

    tank.rotation += differential;
    tank.position.x += Math.cos(tank.rotation) * speed;
    tank.position.y += Math.sin(tank.rotation) * speed;
};
```

- The `engine.update` function will be invoked on every animation frame.
- The `ui.levers.getState` method returns a list of two floats (each
  between `-1` and `1`), representing the state of two levers that
  the user pushes and pulls to control each track.
- In practice, you'll need to multiply or divide some values, else
  your tank will drive too fast, or spin too slowly or something.

Answer (score -1):

Have a vector for each wheel and then calculate the cross product for the direction the tank should be facing with the result of cross(leftWheel, rightWheel);

Comment: You can't use cross on 2d vectors...